# Wix patch always fails when adding components and using '-delta' flag

Tags: wix

My patching system is severely limited in that whenever I need to patch my software product and add any new file I am prevented from using the '-delta' flag. If I do use this flag, when the msp runs it always fails with an error saying '_ComponentID cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in the cabinet file.", which kind of makes sense as the file is indeed not in the original cabinet file (the componentID is referring to the new file I am trying to add). I do not have this problem when not using the '-delta' flag, but then my patches are ending up almost as big as the original installer (most the large files are being altered just a little). I have tried putting the new components in a completely new feature but I always get the same error. 
Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to check:

1. If you are using patchwiz to create your patches (aka: PackageCreation element, aka: .pcp files) then make sure your new files are being added to the end of the sequence using File/@PatchGroup attribute.
2. Set the [MSIENFORCEMINORUPGRADE property](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/1/4/Doing-a-small-update-or-minor-upgrade-in-MSI-Use). That might point out a problem.